# Append option to multi select using ajax with keeping the selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [this](http://loudev.com/#project) multiSelect plugin.

Blade template

```
<form method="POST" id="report-form" action="{{ route('admin.reports.store') }}" aria-label="{{ __('Create Report') }}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label class="control-label mb-10 text-left" for="tableName">Choose Table</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="tableName" id="tableName">
                                        <option>Choose</option>
                                        @foreach ( $tables as $table )
                                            <option value="{{ $table }}">{{ slugFormat($table) }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    @if ($errors->has('tableName'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('tableName') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class="control-label mb-10 text-left" for="columns">Select Column</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="columns[]" id="columns">
                                        <option>Choose</option>
                                    </select>

                                    @if ($errors->has('column'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                           <strong>{{ $errors->first('column') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group mb-0 pull-right">
                                        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                        </form>
```

jQuery code

```
$('#report-form').on('change', '#tableName', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $('#columns').empty();
        $('#columns').append('<option value="">Choose</option>');

        var table = this.value;
        var url = APP_URL + '/admin/reports/columns';

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            type: 'POST',
            data: { table: table },
            success: function(response) {
                if ( response ) {
                    var columns = response.columns;
                    var options = '';
                    for (var i=0; i < columns.length; i++){

                        options += '<option value="'+ table + '.' + columns[i] + '">' + columns[i] + '</option>';
                    }

                    $('#columns').append(options);

                    $('#columns').multiSelect('refresh', {
                        selectableOptgroup: true
                    });
                }
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    });
```

When I am changing the table select, I am getting columns belongs to that table in #columns select box, now if I am selecting some columns from #columns seelect box and changing the table, it is clearing the selected value also, I need to check multiple columns from multiple tables.

[Github Code](https://github.com/PrafullaKumarSahu/lou-multiselect) showing basic implementation of plugin.

Comment: Can you post a working example in either Codepen.io or on the editor here?

Comment: give me two minutes, I will add it to codepen or soemthing. but it is same as the link I have provided. for static data it is working.

Comment: @fylzero I do not have cdn link for the plugin script, if you need, I can share a github repository with working code with static data.

Comment: @fylzero I have just added github repo to question, please have a look at it.

Comment: I downloaded the repo.  When searching all files I can not find the code you've posted anywhere?

Comment: @fylzero I have given you demo code, you need my html? let me add it to the question, but this is taking data from ajax request from db, so this will not work in codepen or something like that.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a working copy of what you are trying to do as a wired example. You could possibly mock out the API call as a json file and just include in the repo...   then I can simply aim the ajax call at the file.

Comment: Obviously, you don't need to post your data.  I would just stub out a json file with the same structure so I can get an idea of what is happening.

Comment: Nevermind.  I have a better idea now with the HTML code.  Let me think about this.

Comment: I would try commenting out the $('#columns').multiSelect('refresh'... block and see if that is what is causing them to clear.  If so, you will likely need to bounce the selections to an array and re-apply them after the refresh.  Also, have you maybe tried calling MultiSelect before the ajax call?  Maybe instantiating it, then adding to it could be an option?  I'm not sure.

Comment: @fylzero let me try your suggestion .

Comment: @fylzero I tried calling multiselect before ajax, that does not solved my problem, second part bounce the selection to array and re-apply them, may be that is one option, but would like to have a better option, sorry for late reply.